# Telegram bot php. Отправка сообщения в текстовое поле, а не в чат

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку бот писал **в текстовую строку юзера**, а не в общий чат. То есть я нажимаю на кнопку "Ваше имя" и в текстовой строке появляется /name и остается ввести только имя. Через switch_inline_query_current_chat все вроде как работает, но добавляется имя бота и бот тогда не видит команду (приватность отключать нельзя). Пробовал через ForceReply, тогда бот видит все, что введено в ответе на его сообщение. Но не знаю, как в Reply добавить команду, чтобы юзеру ее не вбивать.

P.S. Если что, использую - [вот эту библиотеку](https://github.com/TelegramBot/Api) Но был бы рад хотя бы услышать направление, куда копать. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем, кто помог (никто). Вопрос решил. Через ForceReply. Заметил, что тогда шлет данные на хук, даже если включена приватность. Поэтому сделал так - бот спрашивает Ваше имя и снизу ответ - это как reply. Я могу на хуке получить и вопрос, и ответ.